# How to render values onto screen?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to show the results from showUserInfo to show up on the page. How do I do this? I am wondering if I need to create something in the return portion of the code or if it's something else?

````
import React, { useState } from "react"; 
import axios from "axios"; 

export default function App() {

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0); 
  const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState(""); // response 
  const [userInfos, setUserInfos] = useState([]);

  const getAPI = () => {
    axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api')
    .then(function ({ data }) {
      // handle success
      // console.log({ data });
      const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(data); 
      setJsonData(stringifiedData); 
      showUserInfo(data); 
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
    })
  }

  const showUserInfo = ({ results }) => {
    const {0: { name }} = results;
    const {first, last} = name; 
    
    return (<div>`${first} {last}` </div>)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={getAPI}>Get API</button>
      {userInfos}
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Comment: I don't know react so this might be wrong.  It looks like you display userInfos but you never fill it in.  You do fill in jsonData but you don't display it,   showUserInfo is called but the return value is never used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

You can check here, I just made something similar, you can modify it with a few tweaks.

[Button to get User Info](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-glade-1hwmu?file=/src/App.js)

And here's the code that I'm testing:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

let url = "https://randomuser.me/api";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [userInfos, setUserInfos] = useState([]);

  const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState("");
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((res) => {
        const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(res.data);
        setJsonData(stringifiedData);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  });

  const updateUserInfo = () => {
    const data = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    const fullName = data.results[0].name;
    setUserName(fullName);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={updateUserInfo}>Click to Update</button>
      <div className="user">
        {userName.first} {userName.last}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

We use `useEffect` to get the JSON that you need at first, then I setState for it with `setJsonData` like yours. But then in the `updateUserInfo`, you need to parse the jsonData back so we can use it normally because when we get through `useEffect` we've used `stringify`, so it's just a string, not an object like when we parsed complete, then it'll become easier, it'll have a structure like this, for example: `{title: "Mr", first: "Kadir", last: "Balaban"}`. And I create 1 more state called `userName` for testing it. You can try it.

The `{userName.first} {userName.last}` at first render of React will have `undefined` value, so React understand it and will not render, so whenever we click the button, we set the `fullName`, then we call `fullName.first` and `fullName.last`, it'll update the state and render these value into the screen because now React understand that it's not `undefined` anymore.